# How to plot this set of complex numbers?

Tags: plotting, complex, sets

I want to plot this set of complex numbers in Mathematica:
$$
D := \left\{\frac{1}{z}: z \in \mathbb{C}, \text{Im}(z) \ge 1, \text{Re}(z) \le \text{Im}(z), |z-1-i| \le 1\right\}
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The domain of the mapping `1/z` is

```
reg=ImplicitRegion[{y >= 1, x <= y, Abs[x + I*y - 1 - I] <= 1}, {x, y}]
RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
RegionPlot[{x, y} ∈ reg, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2]
RegionPlot[RegionMember[reg, {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

The range of the map `1/z` is

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[1/(x + I*y)], {x, y} ∈reg]
```

For the old version such 12.2, we have to use (maybe a bug)

```
ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[1/(x + I*y)], {x, y} ∈ DiscretizeRegion@reg]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. I know want to change the output range (the part with `AspectRation -> Automatic`, I tried using `RegionPlot[reg, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` but I get an empty plot. How can I do this?

Comment: @Tim see the updated.

Comment: @herbertfederer Nice answer! Any idea why it doesn't work in Mathematica v12.2? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Seems be a bug. Now `ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[1/(x + I*y)], {x, y} ∈ DiscretizeRegion@reg]`

Comment: @herbertfederer Clever, that works. Thanks!

Comment: It's a shame that Mathematica still does not seem to be able to deal directly with this kind of plotting but using complex number per se, without using `ReIm` to split into real and imaginary parts. Years ago, David Park's *Presentations` add-on was able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Just for illustrative purposes:

Parametrizing

```
f[r_, t_, g_] := 
 ReIm@g[ExpToTrig[(Sqrt[2] Exp[I Pi/4] + r Exp[I t])]]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{ParametricPlot[f[r, t, Identity], {r, 0, 1}, {t, Pi/4, Pi}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Point[f[1, a, Identity]], Green, 
      Point[f[s, Pi/4, Identity]], Black, Point[f[w, Pi, Identity]]}],
    ParametricPlot[f[r, t, 1/# &], {r, 0, 1}, {t, Pi/4, Pi}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Point[f[1, a, 1/# &]], Green, 
      Point[f[s, Pi/4, 1/# &]], Black, Point[f[w, Pi, 1/# &]]}]}], {a,
   Pi/4, Pi}, {s, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will be useful for the purposes of visualizing complex numbers.

We can use [**`ComplexListPlot`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html)

With

```
complex = 1/(x + I y);
```

we do

```
ComplexListPlot[
 Callout[#, #] & /@ 
    Flatten[Table[
      If[Im[complex] >= 1 && Re[complex] <= Im[complex] && 
        Abs[complex - 1 - I] <= 1, complex, Nothing], {x, -5, 5, 1/
       50}, {y, -5, 5, 1/50}]] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Quiet]
```

> [image: plot]